# How to prove that complete implies sequentially complete?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, nets

Let us start with a topological vector space (TVS) $X$. We say that $X$ is a **complete** (resp., **sequentially complete**) TVS if each Cauchy net (resp., Cauchy sequence) in $X$ converges to a point of $X$. Can you please help me on how to prove that every complete TVS is sequentially complete.

Comment: That is trivial. A sequence is simply a net over $(\Bbb N,\le)$. And a Cauchy sequence is a Cauchy net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every (Cauchy) sequence ***is*** a (Cauchy) net, indexed by the naturals in the usual order, so this is trivial. You've simply got to prove that an ordered set is a directed set, and you're done.

Comment: :Thanks. My question is trivial. I should have not post it.

Comment: It's okay. I've done it, too. Sometimes we all miss the obvious-in-hindsight.

Comment: This simple thing made me crazy actually. Unforgetable. Thanks once again for your time.

Comment: Although the answer to the question is really that simple other issues concerning nets might be quite different from the case of sequences. For example, "subnets" are not so similar to "subsequences" as many people believe. This is related to the fact that there are compact topological spaces having sequences without any convergent subsequence.

Comment: @Jochen: Good point.

Comment: @juniven: Jochen's point is a good one to keep in mind.